get all calling function inside a function
I'm trying to extract string which comes before "(" followed by ")". Note : there may or maybe nothing in between the braces.
string = "int a = {0}; func1(arg1, arg11); if(var1 == data1 && func2(arg2)) {  var2 = func3(arg3, func4(arg4))  func5(var5) } else { (void)func6(arg6) }"

Tried (in Python 3.12.3):

using re module
 re.findall(r'.*?(?=\s?\().*?(?=\))', string)
 re.findall(r'.*?(?=\s?\()', string)


using regex
  regex.search(r'.*?(\((.*?:[()]|[^()]|(?R))*+\))', string)



desired output:
func1, if, func2, func3, func4, func5, func6
Is there any way to recursively call regex?

Do you need to distinguish between functions and macros?  Between functions and function pointers?  Have you eliminated strings and comments?

Note that in C, if is not a function.

Change .*? before the lookahead to \w+?

why do you need it? Maybe you could write parser with SLY (Sly Lex Yacc) or PLY

re.findall(r'\w+?(?=\s?\(.*?\))', string)

You need to use \w+? at the beginning so the match is just a single token, not everything before the (.
